# General Topology on Complex field?

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation

While Real Analysis is based on spaces of real numbers so we have also Complex Analysis uses complex numbers in its spaces also.

General Topology has commons with Real Analysis and whatever I see in elementry or advanced topics of General Topology are real numbers.

1- Is there a branch of maths that discuss General Topology on complex numbers and fields? If so what is it called?

2- Would someone please introduce some introductory/elementary book on that topic readable for a self-learner like me?

Comment: General topology by definition deals with abstract topological spaces, it is equally valid on the field of complex numbers (with a suitable topology). For that matter, even the special case of metric spaces can apply to the complex field (again, with a suitable metric).

Comment: General topology doesn't really have much at all to do with real numbers or complex numbers; sets are really the only structure underpinning them. The only connection is that metric spaces are an elementary example of a topological space, but even then real numbers are used only to quantify distance, not as the points in the actual space. Even the spaces we look at in complex analysis tend to be metric spaces.